# WPF Chrome window remove gap between windows

Tags: wpf, windows

I am building a WPF library that connects windows.
In the example the windows have the following properties:

```
<Window ...
    Height="150" 
    Width="200" 
    WindowStyle="None" 
    ResizeMode="CanResize"
    Background="#222222"
    AllowsTransparency="False">

<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="1"
                  CornerRadius="0"/>
</WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
```

I use Chrome window because I need to remove the title and be able to resize.
Everything is working well except there are noticeable gaps between windows, although I want to connect them exactly next to each other.

Example layout with 2x magnifier:
https://prnt.sc/26if2vs

What does it cause, can I handle it inside the app, or it caused by the Windows system?

Comment: May be margin in the default style on WindowChrome. Maybe you can try to override margin ?

Comment: I have seen other posts where they mention the  `GlassFrameThickness="0"` in the WindowChrome. not sure if that helps.

Comment: Thank you, yes the GlassFrameThickness is a good solution, but it removes the corner radius of the window as well, but it can be ignored in my case.